# Tracing functions when the arguments are big maps

Tags: clojure, trace

When I trace a function, if one of the arguments is a nested map with a lot of elements, the trace is filled with clutter. Here's a typical example:

```
TRACE t36705: (get-value {:nodeclass :simple, :nodeid :simple25, :dock {:constan
t-dock {:name :constant-dock, :value 22, :dockclass {:name :constant-dock, :link
-policy {:lp-committed? #object[fargish.links$fn__5756 0x407956a5 "fargish.links
$fn__5756@407956a5"], :lp-reciprocate-no-commitment #object[clojure.core$constan
tly$fn__4614 0x69497a36 "clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614@69497a36"], :lp-recipr
ocate-commitment #object[clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614 0x30ee413a "clojure.co
re$constantly$fn__4614@30ee413a"], :lp-can-boost-to #object[fargish.links$fn__57
58 0x5df17e60 "fargish.links$fn__5758@5df17e60"], :lp-official-partners #object[
fargish.links$fn__5760 0x3df2f4ab "fargish.links$fn__5760@3df2f4ab"], :lp-normal
ize-after-add #object[clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614 0x386cc1c4 "clojure.core$
constantly$fn__4614@386cc1c4"], :lp-reduce-to-uncommitted #object[fargish.links$
fn__5765 0x7bd4f212 "fargish.links$fn__5765@7bd4f212"], :lp-committed-to #object
[fargish.links$fn__5767 0x5c3cc103 "fargish.links$fn__5767@5c3cc103"], :lp-boost
 #object[fargish.links$fn__5771 0x423e35f0 "fargish.links$fn__5771@423e35f0"]}, 
:maker #object[fargish.spec_test$eval36501$__GT_Dock_constant_dock__36515 0x19cc
229b "fargish.spec_test$eval36501$__GT_Dock_constant_dock__36515@19cc229b"]}}, :
function-dock {:name :function-dock, :value #fargish.spec.Vfunc{:args (constant-
dock), :f #object[fargish.spec_test$fn__36544 0x135647d3 "fargish.spec_test$fn__
36544@135647d3"]}, :dockclass {:name :function-dock, :link-policy {:lp-committed
? #object[fargish.links$fn__5756 0x407956a5 "fargish.links$fn__5756@407956a5"], 
:lp-reciprocate-no-commitment #object[clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614 0x69497a3
6 "clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614@69497a36"], :lp-reciprocate-commitment #obje
ct[clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614 0x30ee413a "clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614
@30ee413a"], :lp-can-boost-to #object[fargish.links$fn__5758 0x5df17e60 "fargish
.links$fn__5758@5df17e60"], :lp-official-partners #object[fargish.links$fn__5760
 0x3df2f4ab "fargish.links$fn__5760@3df2f4ab"], :lp-normalize-after-add #object[
clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614 0x386cc1c4 "clojure.core$constantly$fn__4614@38
6cc1c4"], :lp-reduce-to-uncommitted #object[fargish.links$fn__5765 0x7bd4f212 "f
argish.links$fn__5765@7bd4f212"], :lp-committed-to #object[fargish.links$fn__576
7 0x5c3cc103 "fargish.links$fn__5767@5c3cc103"], :lp-boost #object[fargish.links
$fn__5771 0x423e35f0 "fargish.links$fn__5771@423e35f0"]}, :maker #object[fargish
.spec_test$eval36523$__GT_Dock_function_dock__36537 0x34584446 "fargish.spec_tes
t$eval36523$__GT_Dock_function_dock__36537@34584446"]}}}} constant-dock)
TRACE t36705: => nil
```

What's a technique for setting things up so these traces print out without so much clutter? I don't expect traces to be super-easy to read, but there has to be a better way than this.

Comment: Have you tried messing around with [`*print-level*`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-clojure-1.6.0/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/*print-level*)?

Comment: How do you setup your tracing? What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe there are better tools but it depends on your specific case.

Comment: @Alex I might be doing something wrong, but `*print-level*` and `*print-length*` seem to have no effect on `clojure.trace`. I'm mostly using `lein test-refresh :with-repl`.

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl The problems that I'm using tracing for vary _a lot_ from case to case. I'm mostly wondering what common wisdom has evolved for how to deal with stuff like large maps in traces. The trace above has lots of function objects in it because it includes a method-map. Other traces can be large for other reasons. The way I set up tracing, usually, is that I change `defn` to `deftrace` in my source code. I've got `lein test-refresh :with-repl` running in one window, so that every time I save my code, my tests run, and any traced functions get traced.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `clojure.tools.trace` doesn't allow customizing the output of trace logs. I wasn't sure if you could modify your source code between runs or you needed a mechanism to plugin into a running system where you cannot modify function implementation.

From your comment it seems you can modify a function you want to trace. Based on your requirement to log only a subset of function's arguments content I would switch to ordinary logging (either with `println` or with some logging framework) and add explicit logging expressions to log only relevant data.

For example:

```
(defn some-function
  [a b]
  (println "some-function" {:a (select-keys a [:x :y]) :b (select-keys b [:x :z])})
  (comment your function body))
```

It's not that easy as changing `defn` to `deftrace` but can be customized any way you want.

Comment: Ah, `select-keys`! Being new to Clojure, many of the common, frequently useful core functions don't yet readily spring to my mind. I haven't used `select-keys` for anything yet, but I will put it to use the next time I'm slogging through a trace with a big map.